# How to install and activate ImageMagick (imagick) with Zend Server?

Tags: ubuntu, imagemagick, zend-server

I'm trying to install and activate ImageMagick with Zend Server (on Ubuntu Server Linux), how could achieve it? (the documentation does not say how to add extra extensions)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Oh, I found it. Just run this:

```
sudo aptitude install php-5.3-imagick-zend-server
```

If you are using PHP 5.2, just make the change in the package name.